# How to implement a j2me client that fetches large data (about 5000 entries) and updates from server in real time

Tags: java, java-me, codenameone

Am using codename one for the client side and java servlet for the server side.

I have a list of information(text, pictures and audio) on the server that changes frequently and a mobile client that let users view these information.

Please, what is the best approach for fetching all these information and reflecting all the changes(updates to the data) on the client in real time, so as to avoid out-of-memory error, long time network lock on the client UI and make the updates appear in real time for all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet needs to provide a limit argument which you can use when sending a request to fetch only a part of the data. You can then use the UI to present only the relevant portion of the data. e.g. using an infinite scrolling paradigm:

http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/09/till-the-end-of-the-form.html

Or using a list model:

http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/cloud/CloudListModel.java

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mr Shai. The infinite scrolling approach is a nice idea here. Limiting the server response will solve the long network delay and reduce server response time( thus increasing the real time feel). But what of the out of memory issue, because am expecting the list to grow up to 1000 elements. May be i should delete the oldest responses, n re-fetch them whenever the user gets closer, but this will increase the size of server downloads( because of the audios, photos and future planned videos). What do you think of this? Should i used some sort of local storage or what?

Comment: @Shai Almong, please, do you think you could help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121003/j2me-how-to-create-a-master-details-ui/24165313?noredirect=1#comment37322057_24165313